# SQL Server take rows and write on 1 row

Tags: sql-server

[image: table]

```
alter function yazarkitap(
@yazarID int)
returns nchar(100)
as
begin
declare @kitaplar nchar(500)
select @yazarID=y_id from yazar 
select (STUFF((select','+kitap_adi from Kitap where @yazarID=y_id FOR XML PATH('')
),1,2,''))as kitapadi
end
```

I'm trying to take `yazar_id` and show all `kitap_adi` have same `yazar_id` in one row. I searched stuff coalesce functions but I couldn't do that.

Comment: Your question is not clear dude.

Comment: when i enter yazar_id in the function i want to see all kitap_adi rows which have same yazar_id in one row

Comment: The @YazarID that is entered as parameter is overwritten by y_id in 'select@yazarID =y_id from yazar'. Your variable kitaplar is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Your writing is a little wrong. You can change it as follows. You will probably get the error again. I suggest you delete it and recreate it.

```
ALTER FUNCTION yazarkitap
(
    @yazarID INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @kitaplar NVARCHAR(MAX)     

    SELECT @kitaplar = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + kitap_adi
            FROM Kitap
            WHERE 
                y_id = @yazarID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

    RETURN @kitaplar

END
```